# GRUB2 не принимает настройки

Tags: linux, centos, centos8

Установлен Centos 8.
Редактирую файл grub2: `nano /etc/default/grub`, устанавливаю:

GRUB_TIMEOUT=30
GRUB_HIDDEN_TIMEOUT_QUIET=false

Сохраняю, проверяю: все сохранилось, ребутаю.

А он как был 5 секунд, так и есть. И запуск тихий, без демонов.
Как поправить?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Загрузчик ничего не знает о `/etc`. Сначала вам необходимо сгенерировать настоящий файл конфигурации grub2. Для ubuntu это делает `update-grub`, в centos - `grub2-mkconfig`.

Для centos у меня в заметках вот такая команда:

```
[ -d /sys/firmware/efi ] && grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/efi/EFI/centos/grub.cfg || grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg
```

Из-за различий, грузится система через UEFI или нет.